# ListView displays incorrect title

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am doing some tests with different characters in the title of a listview.
for some reason the exact same app displays fine on win8 but it doesnt show a check mark in winxp.. how do I fix this on .Net Framework v4?

[image: no check mark found in windows xp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a font problem, you get the rectangle when the machine doesn't have a substitute font with the check-mark glyph, U+2713.

XP did ship with very limited fonts, so this is not entirely unexpected. Run Charmap.exe on that machine so see the glyphs that are available. Ask as superuser.com for the best way to get the machine updated.